# Appending one data frame into another

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to bring three data frames into a single one .All data frames have a single column .

```
org_city_id=p.DataFrame(training_data['origcity_id'])
pol_city_id=p.DataFrame(training_data['pol_city_id'])
pod_city_id=p.DataFrame(training_data['pod_city_id'])
```

All have 100 records in it so my goal is to bring them into a single data frame which will then contain 300 records .My below code is not working

```
org_city_id.append([pol_city_id,pod_city_id])
```

the total number of records in org_city_id is still 100 .

Can someone please suggest .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get a single column name for all your dataframes:

```
org_city_id.columns = pol_city_id.columns = pod_city_id.columns = 'Final Name'
```

Then concat them:

```
pd.concat([org_city_id,pol_city_id,pod_city_id])
```

Answer (score 2):

```
dfs = [org_city_id, pol_city_id, pod_city_id]
pd.concat([df.squeeze() for df in dfs], ignore_index=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [concat](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) from Pandas documentation.

Here is what you'll do:

`pd.concat([org_city_id, pol_city_id, pod_city_id])`

Comment: the problem is all have differnt column names

Comment: @asj177 So change the names accordingly.